# How to import methods from external file that also use "this" in a Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue file that has quite a few methods that I am looking to export into a separate file. The problem is some of these methods make use of the `this` keyword, and I can't figure out how to import these methods properly. Here is a minimal example

**App.vue**

```js
export default {
  ...,
  data () {
    return { // assume these get generated properly through the app
        this.orderAmount = null,
        this.tax = null,
        this.totalAmount = null
        
    }
  },
  methods: {
    assignForAccount () {
      this.totalAmount = this.tax * this.totalAmount
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to move methods such as `assignForAccount` to a separate file called `methods.js`, but it I am getting `undefined` errors when I try to do this:

**App.vue**

```js
import { assignForAccount } from './methods.js'

export default {
  ...,
  data () {
    return { // assume these get generated properly through the app
        this.orderAmount = null,
        this.tax = null,
        this.totalAmount = null

    }
  },
  methods: {
       assignForAccount
    }
}
```

**methods.js**

```
export const assignForAccount = (context) => {
  context.totalAmount = context.tax * context.orderAmount
}
```

TIA

Comment: What's the error? What did you change the code into?

Comment: ` TypeError: Cannot read property 
'tax' of undefined`

Comment: All that was changed is moving the method into methods.js, and importing it in App.vue

Comment: Can you `console.log` `context` in `methods.js`? I would recommend using a function to allow Vue to bind the `this` context to your method.

Comment: How would I do that? Pretty new to vue so I'm not sure what you mean by allow it to bind

Comment: Binding in JavaScript refers to defining a custom context (`this`) inside a given function. Can you log the value of `context` inside your method?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it logs as undefined

Comment: Okay; what you can do is in your `methods.js`, change it to `export const assignForAccount = function() {...}` and change all the `context`s to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass both `this.tax` and `this.totalAmount` from App.vue file into method.js file for the calculations.

method.js **:**

```
export function assignForAccount = (tax, totalAmount) => {
    return tax * totalAmount
}
```

App.vue **:**

```
import { assignForAccount } from './methods.js'

methods: {
    this.totalAmount = assignForAccount(this.tax, this.totalAmount);
}
```